# SQL Determine if 2 of N Columns have a Specific Value

Tags: sql, oracle, permutation

I want to know if there's a way in SQL (specifically Oracle SQL) to identify the following:

I have 10 columns, call them A,B,...,J. Each of these columns is a Y/N field. I want to be able to determine for a given row if at least two of the columns are "Y". I was going to do a *case when* statement but I don't know if there's a simple way to do this without writing out every single permutation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the `Y` to 1 and `N` to 0 and then sum the values across the columns and if it adds up to 2 or more then you have at least two columns containing `Y`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c27e2/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J ) AS
SELECT 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  DECODE( A, 'Y', 1, 0 )
     + DECODE( B, 'Y', 1, 0 )
     + DECODE( C, 'Y', 1, 0 )
     + DECODE( D, 'Y', 1, 0 )
     + DECODE( E, 'Y', 1, 0 )
     + DECODE( F, 'Y', 1, 0 )
     + DECODE( G, 'Y', 1, 0 )
     + DECODE( H, 'Y', 1, 0 )
     + DECODE( I, 'Y', 1, 0 )
     + DECODE( J, 'Y', 1, 0 ) >= 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c27e2/2/0)**:

```
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| N | Y | N | Y | N | N | N | N | N | N |
| N | N | Y | N | N | N | Y | N | Y | N |
```

You could also use `CASE a WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` instead of the `DECODE` function.

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CASE A WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     + CASE B WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     + CASE C WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     + CASE D WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     + CASE E WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     + CASE F WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     + CASE G WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     + CASE H WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     + CASE I WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     + CASE J WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END >= 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c27e2/2/1)**:

```
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| N | Y | N | Y | N | N | N | N | N | N |
| N | N | Y | N | N | N | Y | N | Y | N |
```

Comment: I get an error "Line 12:0 Arguments length mismatch '0': Decode() requires exactly two arguments" however I wonder if I can do the same with the INSTR() function and sum that way?

Comment: @fordo19 Updated with an SQL Fiddle - `DECODE` [takes multiple arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions057.htm#SQLRF00631), not just 2.

Comment: thanks, I was able to use the case when function to get what I need!

Answer (score 0):

A `case when` is complicated.

I would go for `regexp_count()`:

```
select regexp_count(a||b||c||d||e||f||g||h||i||j, 'Y')
```

Comment: Why regular expressions for this when they are so slow? You could use `REPLACE` and `LENGTH` and just use standard string functions. Also, I hope you would also document this properly as someone coming back to it in a few years to try to maintain this code will not always find it easy to see what the code it trying to achieve.

Comment: @MT0 . . . This seems like the most direct and shortest way to  the answer.